# Automatically dim keyboard backlight if VLC is playing

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player, backlight

Would it be possible to automatically dim (turn off) keyboard backlight if media player (namely VLC) is playing?

Could it for example be coded with applescript?

The use case is I've find myself only dimming the backlight watching movies, so I wouldn't have to manage it manually all the time.

Comment: Why can't you in the Apple menu -> System Preferences -> Keyboard adjust the keyboard slider to turn off illumination for example after 1 minute of inactivity?

Comment: @harrymc I use that right now and while that's quite a good solution, I would prefer the keyboard always dimmed while playing a movie and having long delay when working. I set the delay to 10 seconds, but that means every time I adjust the volume while the movie is playing, there are 10 seconds of distracting backlight. It's a petty problem though :)

Comment: The only solution is to manually turn backlight off/on during play. You could use an applescript to do that if going into keyboard preferences is too tiresome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by an AppleScript to dim the keyboard then start the VLC player.
You can get the script for dimming the backlight from here:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3371560

(I don't want to violate any copyrights)
And to open VLC add following lines at the end,

```
tell application "VLC" to activate
 end tell
```

If you are new to AppleScript this would help.
http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_running_applescripts_terminal.